# Another simple RegEx match

Tags: regex

Trying to get the correct regexp syntax to match marked lines (with *):

```
#32 0 0 A [2] *
#13 3 2 A [1]
#44 1 2 A [2]
#44 0 0 A [1]
#44 0 0 A [2] *
#44 0 0 B [2] *
```

What I want, is lines containing "0 0" and somewhere after that "[2]". Any character can occur before, in between, or after those two rules.

This is what I have today, which finds the first part:

```
#.. 0 0
```

How do I complete it?

Also, If anyone want to share a good URL for a regex rookie like me I'd be even more thankful!

Comment: hint: alternation is `|`.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: What flavor of regex? Perl, Python POSIX ERE, etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `what I want, is lines containing "0 0" and somewhere after that "[2]". Any character can occur before, in between

You can use this regex:

```
^#[0-9]{2} 0 0.*?\[2\]
```

**Explanation:**

```
^ assert position at start of the string
# matches the character # literally
[0-9]{2} match a single character present in the list below
Quantifier: Exactly 2 times
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
 0 0 matches the characters  0 0 literally
.*? matches any character (except newline)
Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
\[ matches the character [ literally
2 matches the character 2 literally
\] matches the character ] literally
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
echo '#32 0 0 A [2]
#13 3 2 A [1]
#44 1 2 A [2]
#44 0 0 A [1]
#44 0 0 A [2]
#44 0 0 B [2]' | grep -E '.*0 0.*\[2\].*'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
#.. 0 0.*\[2\].*
```